# LINQ - GroupBy multiple columns and merge the result

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with sizeable set of data (~130.000 records), I've managed to transform it the way I want it (to csv).

Here is a simplified example of how the List looks like:

> ```
> "Surname1, Name1;Address1;State1;YES;Group1"
> "Surname2, Name2;Address2;State2;YES;Group2"
> "Surname2, Name2;Address2;State2;YES;Group1" 
> "Surname3, Name3;Address3;State3;NO;Group1"
> "Surname1, Name1;Address2;State1;YES;Group1"
> ```

Now, I would like to merge the records if 1st, 2nd AND 3rd column match, like so:

> output
>
> ```
> "Surname1, Name1;Address1;State1;YES;Group1"
> "Surname2, Name2;Address2;State2;YES;Group2 Group1"
> "Surname3, Name3;Address3;State3;NO;Group1"
> "Surname1, Name1;Address2;State1;YES;Group1"
> ```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
output.GroupBy(x => new { c1 = x.Split(';')[0], c2 = x.Split(';')[1], c3 = x.Split(';')[2] }).Select(//have no idea what should go here);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to get the columns you need projecting the result in an anonymous type:

```
var query=  from r in output
            let columns= r.Split(';')
            select new { c1 =columns[0], c2 =columns[1], c3 = columns[2] ,c5=columns[4]};
```

And then create the groups but now using the anonymous object you define in the previous query:

```
var result= query.GroupBy(e=>new {e.c1, e.c2, e.c3})
                 .Select(g=> new {SurName=g.Key.c1,
                                  Name=g.Key.c2,
                                  Address=g.Key.c3,
                                  Groups=String.Join(",",g.Select(e=>e.c4)});
```

I know I'm missing some columns but I think you can get the idea.

PS: The fact I have separated the logic in two queries is just for readability propose, you can compose both queries in one but that is not going to change the performance because LINQ use [deferred evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> input = new List<string> {
            "Surname1, Name1;Address1;State1;YES;Group1",
            "Surname2, Name2;Address2;State2;YES;Group2",
            "Surname2, Name2;Address2;State2;YES;Group1",
            "Surname3, Name3;Address3;State3;NO;Group1",
            "Surname1, Name1;Address2;State1;YES;Group1",
    };
        var transformed = input.Select(s => s.Split(';'))
            .GroupBy(   s => new string[] { s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3] }, 
                        (key, elements) => string.Join(";", key) + ";" + string.Join(" ", elements.Select(e => e.Last())), 
            new MyEqualityComparer())
            .ToList();

    }
}

internal class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        return x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        int hashCode = obj[0].GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode ^ obj[1].GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode ^ obj[2].GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Consider the first 4 columns as the grouping key, but only use the first 3 for the comparison (hence the custom `IEqualityComparer`).
Then if you have the (key, elements) groups, transform them so that you join the elements of the key with ; (remember, the key consists of the first 4 columns) and add to it the last element from every member of the group, joined with a space.